# Dotted line do not display when print

Tags: printpdf

My visual page render as pdf, at prepare print screen my dotted line can display but when I printed the dotted line disappear on my paper . Can any body help me.

Comment: can you post your code as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue in chrome browser. this is the issue link https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539533

But this is working in Mozilla firefox browser

I used below code. Worked for me

```
.dotClass{
    border-top:.5pt dotted black;line-height: 0px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<tr><td colspan="8" class="dotClass">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

You try with this. Hope this will work for you

Comment: thanks @Ranta It did not work for me. But I realize that, if I use firefox , it working fine, but not whit chrome.  any problem with my chrome' setting  ?

Comment: I am using chrome `Version 47` it is working fine for me

Comment: it's seem Chrome's problem . I found this https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539533

Comment: Cool..... this is known issue. Thank god no issue with my code ohh